# How to use loop for create map in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a questions - how to use for to create map in javascript?
My actually code:

```
wall_array = [{x:0,y:0},{x:0,y:1},{x:0,y:2},{x:0,y:3},{x:0,y:4},{x:0,y:5},{x:0,y:6},{x:0,y:7},{x:0,y:8},{x:0,y:9},{x:0,y:10},{x:0,y:11},{x:0,y:12},{x:0,y:13},{x:0,y:14},{x:0,y:15},{x:0,y:16},{x:0,y:17},{x:0,y:18},{x:0,y:19},{x:0,y:20},{x:0,y:30},{x:0,y:31},{x:0,y:32},{x:0,y:33},{x:0,y:34},{x:0,y:35},{x:0,y:36},{x:0,y:37},{x:0,y:38},{x:0,y:39},{x:0,y:40},{x:0,y:41},{x:0,y:42},{x:0,y:43},{x:0,y:44},{x:0,y:45},{x:0,y:46},{x:0,y:47},{x:0,y:48},{x:0,y:49},{x:1,y:0},{x:2,y:0},{x:3,y:0},{x:4,y:0},{x:5,y:0},{x:6,y:0},{x:7,y:0},{x:8,y:0},{x:9,y:0},{x:10,y:0},{x:11,y:0},{x:12,y:0},{x:13,y:0},{x:14,y:0},{x:15,y:0},{x:30,y:0},{x:31,y:0},{x:32,y:0},{x:33,y:0},{x:34,y:0},{x:35,y:0},{x:36,y:0},{x:37,y:0},{x:38,y:0},{x:39,y:0},{x:40,y:0},{x:41,y:0},{x:42,y:0},{x:43,y:0},{x:44,y:0},{x:1,y:49},{x:2,y:49},{x:3,y:49},{x:4,y:49},{x:5,y:49},{x:6,y:49},{x:7,y:49},{x:8,y:49},{x:9,y:49},{x:10,y:49},{x:11,y:49},{x:12,y:49},{x:13,y:49},{x:14,y:49},{x:15,y:49},{x:30,y:49},{x:31,y:49},{x:32,y:49},{x:33,y:49},{x:34,y:49},{x:35,y:49},{x:36,y:49},{x:37,y:49},{x:38,y:49},{x:39,y:49},{x:40,y:49},{x:41,y:49},{x:42,y:49},{x:43,y:49},{x:44,y:49},{x:44,y:1},{x:44,y:2},{x:44,y:3},{x:44,y:4},{x:44,y:5},{x:44,y:6},{x:44,y:7},{x:44,y:8},{x:44,y:9},{x:44,y:10},{x:44,y:11},{x:44,y:12},{x:44,y:13},{x:44,y:14},{x:44,y:15},{x:44,y:16},{x:44,y:17},{x:44,y:18},{x:44,y:19},{x:44,y:20},{x:44,y:30},{x:44,y:31},{x:44,y:32},{x:44,y:33},{x:44,y:34},{x:44,y:35},{x:44,y:36},{x:44,y:37},{x:44,y:38},{x:44,y:39},{x:44,y:40},{x:44,y:41},{x:44,y:42},{x:44,y:43},{x:44,y:44},{x:44,y:45},{x:44,y:46},{x:44,y:47},{x:44,y:48}];
```

Can I write shorter?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use nested loops...

```
var wall_array = [];
for (var j = 0; j < 50; ++j) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
     results.push ({x : j, y : i});
  }
}
```

Comment: Look again in my code please... Nested loops doesn't work, because I don't want x 0:50, y 0:50

Comment: so just change it to 49..what's the problem?

Comment: I need:
x 0, y 0:49 |
x 0:44, y 0 |
x 1:44 y 49 |
x 44 y 1:48 |
and this is my problem. Ordinary loop as your exemple is really easy. So my problem is also - can I  even write shorter?

Comment: I'm sorry I really do not understand. can you please explain once more.. I do not know what you mean.. what is x0, y 0:49? x: 0:44, y0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the x and y pattern of your data, I came up with the following for loop (along with some if logic).

```
var wall_array = [];
var x, y;

for(x = 0; x <= 44; x++) {
    if(x == 0) {
        for (y = 0; y <= 20; y++) {
            wall_array.push({x: x, y: y});
        }

        for(y = 30; y <= 49; y++) {
            wall_array.push({x: x, y: y});
        }
    }

    if(x >= 1 && x <= 15) {
        wall_array.push({x: x, y: 0});
        wall_array.push({x: x, y: 49});
    }

    if(x >= 30 && x <= 44) {
        wall_array.push({x:x, y: 0});
        wall_array.push({x:x, y: 49});
    }

    if(x == 44) {
        for(y=1; y<=20; y++) {
            wall_array.push({x:x, y:y});            
        }

        for(y=30; y<=48; y++) {
            wall_array.push({x:x, y:y});            
        }
    }
}
```